# Why there is no SDLK_COLON equivalent scancode in SDL2?

Tags: c, sdl-2

I'm trying to check if the colon key is pressed, I'm using a English keyboard which means colon is `shift` + `;`, my though was to read the keyboard state and then check the status of the scancode:

```
  SDL_PumpEvents();
  const uint8 *keyState = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

  printf("keystate %d\n", keyState[scancode]);
```

but then I realized there is a scancode for the keypad colon `SDL_SCANCODE_KP_COLON` equivalent to`SDLK_KP_COLON`, but there is no scancode for `SDLK_COLON` (In case you are wondering: I tried with the keypad version and is not working).

So, I wonder why there is no equivalent scancode for `SDLK_COLON` and what's the best way to do this instead?

Comment: Check `Shift`+`;` separately. Scancodes are for physical buttons, `:` isn't a separate button.

Comment: Right, but I would like to do it in a way that's layout agnostic. My understanding is keycodes are for buttons but scancodes are meant to be layout agnostic.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "agnostic". Scancodes are for physical button locations, they ignore the labels printed on keycaps (e.g. WASD game controls should use scancodes, that'll remap to ZQSD on AZERTY), while keycodes correspond to symbols on keycaps (text editing should use keycodes).

Comment: Well, let's put it this way: what if I don't know the current layout, how can I check if the right combinations of keys that correspond to `:` are pressed?

Comment: Either a keycode, or `SDL_TEXTEDITING` event (the latter respects the current language setting, for folks switching between 2+ languages). You'd use a scancode if you wanted 'a key two positions to the left from Enter'.

Comment: Can you tell us what you're using the hotkeys for?

Comment: Sure, I'm building an UI and when you press `:` it should open a command line bar vim style

Comment: Depends on how you want your users to memorize this hotkey. Is it "shift + whatever is under my right pinky"? Then scancode. Or is it "as if you want to type `:`"? Then keycode or `SDL_TEXTEDITING`. Vim uses the latter, but terminals don't expose anything other than `SDL_TEXTEDITING`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251870/discussion-between-hugo-and-holyblackcat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no colon scancode because there is no key on an ANSI (US) layout keyboard that produces a colon without modifiers. [`SDLK_COLON`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_Keycode) exists because there are layouts where a key produces a colon without modifier, like the French layout where the key corresponding to `SDL_SCANCODE_PERIOD` (dot `.` or greater-than sign `>`) makes a colon `:` or a slash `/` (with shift). So if you press that key on a French keyboard, you receive an event with `SDL_SCANCODE_PERIOD` and `SDLK_COLON`.

What I assume you want is to know if the user *typed* a colon, which has nothing to do with scancodes or even keycodes when dealing with different keyboard layouts. For that, you need a [`SDL_TextInputEvent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_TextInputEvent). Check out [the wiki's tutorial](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/Tutorials-TextInput) about it.

Or you could use `SDL_SCANCODE_SEMICOLON`, check what that key corresponds to for the user, and display that so the user knows what key to press (it would be the `ù` key for a French keyboard).